# php pthreads reading a file line by line

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to read a file line by line, and run each line through my code cycle, all of this works fine already, but I'm wondering how I can multithread this properly using pthreads....
I already have pthreads installed, I just need to see an example on how to read a file line by line, and run my code cycle for each line, without running the same line twice because of multithreading....

Is this possible, or am I wasting my time?
These files I'm running the php script on are big, and can be over 150,000 lines....

```
$file = file('list.txt');
//For each file as "kek"/
ForEach ($file as $kek){
//Split the new line.
    $splitter = explode(":", $kek);
    $var1 = $splitter[0];
    $var2 = $splitter[1];
    $var3 = $splitter[2];
    $var4 = $splitter[3];

    //execute the rest of the code that you need the separated vars for....
}
```

edit:
So, I've done a little bit of reading, and I believe what I need is a pool....
I currently have php 5.5 installed, and pthreads v2, is a pool what I need?

Comment: You could 'assign' each thread to read a block of lines, assuming that order isn't important.  So thread 1 does 1-1000, 2 does 1001 to 2000...

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily I have added the sample code for what I need multithreaded.

Comment: @NigelRen The file size is going to vary a lot, since the file I will be sorting will be different pretty much every time the file is ran, would this still work, and could I get some sort of example or a link to an example?

Comment: It's one approach, you would have to try it out.  You could guestimate the number of lines from the file size and a rough idea of how long each line is. You don't want to run too many threads as this can cause bottlenecks with disk and database access (also depends on the number of cores your machine has)

Answer (score -1):

You can use command **split** in Linux , it can be split you file txt become 2 files or more what you want.

You can try command

**split -l 500 file.txt** -> for 500 lines each file split
**split -C 10M file.txt** -> for 10 MB size of each file split